# Using FluentValidation to check if a string is a number greater than zero

Tags: fluentvalidation

I've started using `FluentValidation` on a WPF project, till now I used it in a simple way checking if a field has been filled or less then n character.

Now I've to check if the value inserted (which is a string...damn old code) is greater then 0. Is there a simple way I can convert it using

```
RuleFor(x=>x.MyStringField).Somehow().GreaterThen(0) ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just write a custom validator like this

```
public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Test>
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.MyString)
                .Custom((x, context) =>
                {
                    if ((!(int.TryParse(x, out int value)) || value < 0))
                    {
                        context.AddFailure($"{x} is not a valid number or less than 0");
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

And from your place where you need to validate do this

```
var validator = new Validator();
var result = validator.Validate(test);
Console.WriteLine(result.IsValid ? $"Entered value is a number and is > 0" : "Fail");
```

### Update 11/8/21

If you are going to use this on a large project or API, you are probably better by doing this from the `Startup` and we don't need to manually call the `validator.Validate()` in each and every method.

```cs
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
                {
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<BaseValidator>();
                    fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                    fv.ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
                })
```

Answer (score 11):

Another solution:

```
RuleFor(a => a.MyStringField).Must(x => int.TryParse(x, out var val) && val > 0)
.WithMessage("Invalid Number.");
```

Comment: `Must` has really helped me, I was trying with old Transform extension method from older version, but this is super clean and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **transformation**:  https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/transform.html

```
Transform(from: x => x.SomeStringProperty, to: value => int.TryParse(value, out int val) ? (int?) val : null)
.GreaterThan(0);
```